How to show select option list on hover?
I want to show select option list on hover, but it's not working:
<div className="rating-option">
    <select
        id="rating"
        className="rating"
        value={rating}
        onChange={(e) => setRating(e.target.value)}
    >
        <option value="">Select Rating</option>
        <option value="1">1- Bad</option>
        <option value="2">2- Fair</option>
        <option value="3">3- Good</option>
        <option value="4">4- Very good</option>
        <option value="5">5- Excelent</option>
    </select>
</div>

CSS applied to that code:
.rating-option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
}
.rating-option:hover .rating {
  display: list-item;
  background-color: red;
}
#rating {
  position: absolute;
}

